# Properties is overwriting in prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm not an expert in js. But recently I started writing with prototypes and faced with such issue.

I have class Test and object (attributes) like a property of this class. Then I create instances collection with different attributes. Unfortunately, I get collection with the same attributes, which are the same with last instance attributes.
I suppose it's easier to understand when you see the code.

```
function Test(id) {
   this.init(id);
}

Test.prototype = {
    attributes : {
        id : null,
    },

    init : function (id) {
        this.attributes.id = id;
    }
};

var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = {};


for(var i in a) {
    b[i] = new Test(a[i]);
}

console.log(b);
```

[image: this result I have]

Could you explain me a cause and how can I avoid this trouble?
Thanks a lot

Comment: All properties are 4((

Comment: The prototype is shared between all instances of a "class". If you want individual instances to have specific properties, assign them on a per instance basis. `this.attributes = {}`, not `prototype.attributes = {}`.

Comment: "*I have class Test*" - there are no classes in JS.

Comment: @melpomene: There are in ES6 (sort of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype is shared between each of the instances of `Test`. For this reason, once it is set in any of the instances, it is also changed for all other instances.

To avoid this, you can make the id an attribute of the instance itself, not of the prototype:

```js
function Test(id) {
    this.init(id);
}
    
Test.prototype = {
    init : function (id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
};
    
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];      
    
for(var i in a) {
    console.log(new Test(a[i]));
}
```

By not declaring the id as an attribute of the prototype, it is by default treated as an attribute of the instance.

Comment: Or if you still wanted the`attributes` object, you could add this to the "constructor" (above `this.init(id);`): `this.attributes = {id: null};`.

Comment: Or even `this.attributes = { id: id };` in `init`.